# How can i play acoustic guiter in Ubuntu? Like placing cords making leads and playing it

Tags: 12.04, sound, package-management, music, multimedia

Is there any package available for Ubuntu which allows me to create guiter music such as cords place and making lead melody, edit/delete/etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**TuxGuitar** [image: Install tuxguitar]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/tuxguitar) might be what you're looking for.

You can find more info on [TuxGuitar's website](http://www.tuxguitar.com.ar/).

Comment: 1) installed tux guiter from there download 2) no sound 3) apt-get install tuxguitar-jsa 4) then i have sound . Thanks it works.